# How do I import a SQLite table into R and preserve its NA values?

Tags: r, sqlite, na

I created an SQLite database that contains three tables and I want to analyze these tables in R. Two of these tables have missing data that I entered as "NA" in the initial .csv file. The import into R with the code below goes smoothly, but the dbReadTable function generates a warning that several of my columns have two data types. When I look at the new tables after they've been formed, I see all the NA values were transformed into zeroes.

```
DB <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "/myfilepath.db")


# Show list of all tables
as.data.frame(dbListTables(DB))

# select desired data table
water <- dbReadTable(DB, 'water_TBL')
plants <- dbReadTable(DB, 'plants_TBL')
soil <- dbReadTable(DB, 'soil_TBL')
```

The warning message appears as follows:

```
Warning messages:
1: In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
  Column `biomass_g`: mixed type, first seen values of type real, coercing other values of type string
```

How do I get the dbReadTable function to preserve NA values and not convert them?

The data frame that does not contain NA values imports perfectly, and I can manipulate it just like I would any other data frame.

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular provide minimal reproducible input so others can see the details.  In this case it would mean providing several lines of the csv file, self contained R or other code to create the SQLite database from those lines and the code attempt to read it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.